# Compiling Code - Creating an IDE

Tags: java, command-line, compiler-construction, ide

I've been deving an IDE for Java, Assembly and JMM for the last two months, and have been able to have the JMM compiler to run through the IDE and compile the given code. For some reason,
I cannot seem to find a way to do this with Java code. Is there any API call I can use to compile a given class or even somehow invoke javac and give it the necessary values through the command line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**The IDE:**

[image]

Comment: `Runtime.exec()` with `javac` should do the trick, if the class is in a file.

Comment: See [Java Compiler API](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/guide/compilerAPI.html) in javax.tools (ships after Java 1.6 nad later). [Example (see accepted answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173294/compiling-fully-in-memory-with-javax-tools-javacompiler)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [a URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to load the source code of the class and [a JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) to compile it.

Contrived example: [URLClassLoader and accessibility of package-private methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282726/urlclassloader-and-accessibility-of-package-private-methods)