# Is there a way to create class(not instance) dynamically?

Tags: java

I have an issue about how to create class(not instance) dynamically.
In my project, I need to write several similar class according to the configuration file.
For exmaple, there is a JSON like this:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                          
        "lang": "python",                                                                                                                                                      
        "file": "class1.py",
        "args": ["arg1"]                                                                                                                                  
    },                                                                                                                                                                         
    {                                                                                                                                                                          
        "lang": "python",                                                                                                                                                      
        "file": "class2.py"  
        "args": ["arg2"]                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Subsequently, I need to write two java class below:

class1:

```
public class Class1 extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {
    public Class1() {
        super("python", "class1.py");
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields(arg1));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

class2:

```
public class Class2 extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {

    public Class2() {
        super("python", "class2.py");
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields(arg2));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But if the JSON file is added a new object:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                          
    "lang": "python",                                                                                                                                                      
    "file": "class3.py"   
    "args": ["arg3"]
}
```

I need to write a new Class with the similar structure.
So, is there a way to create class dynamically?
I know maybe cglib might works, but I hava no idea how to use it in my case.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to create these classes? Why wouldn't it be sufficient to have just one class which encapsulates the JSON-Object from the configuration file and has methods which behave according to the content of that object?

Comment: there are libraries like [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) that allow you to create classes at run time

Comment: This is an article discussing a similar problem: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200711/Journal200711.jsp#a4

Comment: @Philipp hi philipp, I know somebody might have this question. But unfortunately, the frame work I used here just needs to be like this. The Instances of the similar classes will be used later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) to compile any java code to a class file. You can then load the resulting class with a [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

An example is given in the javadocs or for a complete example you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282726/urlclassloader-and-accessibility-of-package-private-methods).

Applied to your `Class1` it would look like the example below. Note that you need to include all the relevant imports in the code or it won't compile.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String packageName = "some.packagename";
    String className = packageName + ".Class1";
    String body = "package " + packageName + ";   " +
                "public class Class1 extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {\n" +
                "    public Class1() {\n" +
                "        super(\"python\", \"class1.py\");\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    @Override\n" +
                "    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {\n" +
                "        declarer.declare(new Fields(arg1));\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    @Override\n" +
                "    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {\n" +
                "        return null;\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";

    Path classFile = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    compile(className, body, classFile);
    Class<?> class1 = loadClass(className, classFile);

    Method getComponentConfiguration = class1.getDeclaredMethod("getComponentConfiguration");
    Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) getComponentConfiguration.invoke(class1.newInstance());
}

private static Class<?> loadClass(String className, Path path) throws Exception {
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{path.toUri().toURL()}, Test1.class.getClassLoader());
    return loader.loadClass(className);
}

private static void compile(String className, String body, Path path) throws Exception {
    List<JavaSourceFromString> sourceCode = Arrays.asList(new JavaSourceFromString(className, body));

    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(path.toFile()));
    boolean ok = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, sourceCode).call();

    System.out.println("compilation ok = " + ok);
}

public static class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    final String code;

    JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.', '/') + JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE.extension),
                JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE);
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to create classes in JVM dynamically, consider using dynamic languages such as Groovy.

Another way: if you need to interpret some Python code on JVM - consider using Jython. http://www.jython.org/

There's a danger on creating classes in HotSpot JVM dynamically. If you will create too many dynamic classes, you may run out of PermGen space, and your JVM will crash with `OutOfMemory` error. However, there's some workarounds about it, such as enabling garbage collection for PermGen via `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` jvm parameters. It is announced than PermGen will be removed in JVM 8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You should create your own [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) implementation, override its `loadClass` method and there call `defineClass`, providing it with the bytecode. There is no built-in classes to generate bytecode, but you can always use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). Then you instantiate you `ClassLoader` and get your class from it that way:

```
ClassLoader myClassLoader = new MyClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
Class<?> generatedClass = Class.forName("pkg.GeneratedClass", true, myClassLoader);
Object instance = generatedClass.newInstance();
```

There is an example of how your `loadClass` might be implemented:

```
@Override public void loadClass(String name) {
    if (name.equals("pkg.GeneratedClass")) {
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
        cw.visit(V1_6, ACC_PUBLIC, "pkg/GeneratedClass", null, "java/lang/Object", null);
        // and so on, use ASM API to complete class generation,
        // see asm documentation
        byte[] bytecode = cw.toByteArray();
        return defineClass(name, bytecode, 0, bytecode.length);
    } else {
        return super.loadClass(name);
    }
}
```